# exFAT drive accessible from linux is inaccessible from Windows, Disk Management recognizes the drive but is unallocated

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, mount

I had been using an external 2TB HDD on my Raspberry Pi, and I had it formatted so that when I needed to access the files from Windows, I would be able to. However, now that I attempt to do so, I am unable to. The file is not mounted automatically, in Disk Management, the disk is recognized but it says "Unallocated, as if the drive was not only blank, but had no assigned partitions. I have verified on my Pi that it is indeed exFAT, after checking my `/etc/fstab`, checking with `fsck`, checking with `fdisk`, and they all say it is exFAT. Does anybody know what I can do to remedy this?

Comment: What does `fdisk` say about the disk? How is the disk physically connected to Windows – is it still external?

Comment: What does the fstab line say and what is the disk identifier on Linux?  I'm wondering if you have formatted the disk, rather then create a partition and format that - which I believe is what Windows expects.